# Wordpress admin bar not showing on frontend when logged in

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-admin

The thing is that I found a lot article on the internet that briefs like this,

1. check footer.php for `<?php wp_footer(); ?>`
2. check header.php for `<?php wp_head(); ?>`
3. check function.php for

```
    function my_function_admin_bar() {
        return false;
    }

    add_filter('show_admin_bar', 'my_function_admin_bar');
```

4. Check if in user profile show toolbar ticked on.

I checked all of that and everything is fine and in order. It seems it creating a white space before the header but it is actually not showing up with quick access buttons on the frontend.

N.B: Previously it was displaying the admin bar but all of a sudden it just disappeared.

Please help to fix this...

Answer (score 1):

Do you still have the code you listed as #3 of your question (the function in `function.php`) included? If yes, delete that - `return false` *hides* the admin bar....

Answer (score 0):

first put this:`<?php wp_footer(); ?>`  after this
`<?php get_header(); /*Template Name: Debut Party*/ ?>`